# I am getting the Error "InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list"

Tags: infopath

Getting error while trying to customize the list in infopath. Anyone can help solving this issue. Also when i am trying to open from list setting->Form setting, i am getting the message like "the list does not have any valid content type."
[image: Infopath form]

[image: Getting error while clicking on form setting]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it on other lists? Which type of list is this and what is the content type?